# Broken image (error code 400) for some Facebook avatars

Tags: bug, profile-picture, facebook, link-rot

I noticed a broken image on [this profile](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/15535/bella-lester). Closer inspection showing the avatar throw error with status code 400, for this url: https://graph.facebook.com/280988338943803/picture?type=large

Probably the person deleted their facebook account at some point, resulting in the broken avatar.

Can this please be fixed so it will either fallback to the facebook anonymous avatar, or reset to show identicon?

Comment: How would SE know the facebook account got deleted?

Comment: @rene pretty easy to catch error when requesting the image with server side request, e.g. scheduled job scanning all Facebook avatars daily, for those that return error status, reset the avatar. Also, I assume Facebook does have API that returns basic user data based on their ID, but it would probably require more dev time on SE side.

Comment: Isn't that similar to what was tried with the broken links review queue. That is a lot of accounts to check?

Comment: @rene I don't think there are many with active Facebook avatar, wonder if we can get data with SEDE?

Comment: over a million: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/952158

Comment: @rene oh my. So... maybe even ugly client side hack using `onerror`.

Comment: meh, not worth the effort.

Comment: Looks like the error code is now 100 instead of 400?

Comment: @Bookends It's the HTTP status code that is 400, not the number in the response. That is [still 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdMPt.png).

Comment: @Bookends as Dan said, I'm referring to the "public" error code, not the internal Facebook error which is less relevant for us as users.