# Gravatars not loaded for certain sources

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture, gravatar

There are some user gravatars that aren't loading properly. Searching through the [list of New Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers) (just because it was easiest finding missing gravatars within that list) there seems to be a number of users with their gravatars pointing to "malformed or illegal requests." Some examples:

- [User 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/872432/anderson): Gravatar URL points to googleusercontent.com
- [User 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/857144/floyd-everest): Gravatar URL points to graph.facebook.com

This is not particular to googleusercontent.com or graph.facebook.com gravatars as here are some valid gravatars:

- [User 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/882765/norhther): Gravatar URL points to googleusercontent.com
- [User 4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/861506/olivier-darrouzet): Gravatar URL points to graph.facebook.com

Can someone identify what the problem is here and/or why this is occurring? Is it possible to fix this?

- Most valid gravatar URLs point to SE's Imgur account or Gravatar.com.
- Original reference posted on [Meta.TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8694/5764)

Comment: @Ollie: There's a little more detail to my question, as it identifies an additional URL (Facebook) where this issue arises. I think we need to merge the two to broaden the scope of the original Google-specific problem.

Comment: Related: [Invalid size parameters break avatars served by Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355948/168244)

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: Related question on Meta.ru.SO: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10948/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5

Comment: @MadScientist: Chrome.